# Javascript Drop Target from External Sites

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have an HTML list object and I would like to enable this as a drop target for links dragged from an external site.

More precisely, I have my list, and I want to be able to drag videos from Youtube and then run a function on the link that it provides. How do I check what link was dragged into the window? And I also dont want the window to try and redirect the entire page to the link, is this possible?

EDIT: Adding what code I have:

I have this list:

```
 <ul  id="playlistList">
  </ul>
```

And I populate it with items based on video links, so I run my function that takes a link and makes an li object:

```
//Adds object
AddItem(link)
```

What I need is a way to intercept the dragged video on the window and take the link, run the function, then stop navigation.

Comment: Could you post your code that you have so far? There are a lot of different ways of approaching this so it would be helpful to have a baseline. Thanks!

Comment: I have added what code I do have